# EF6 Code First not mapping my M-0 relationsip

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm looking to be able to type `SupplyPoint.SupplyPointMeters` and for the latter to be a collection. Code First has created the tables and set the Foreign key correctly but I want to be able to access `SupplyPoint.SupplyPointMeters` that way.

So in Summary `SupplyPointMeter` always has a `SupplyPoint` but `SupplyPoint` can have `0` or more `SupplyPoint` Meters. Everything works but I want the relationships to join up automatically to support dot notation.

```
public partial class SupplyPointMeter
{
    [Key]
    public int SupplyPointMeterId { get; set; }
    public int SupplyPointId { get; set; }

    [Key,ForeignKey("SupplyPointId")]
    public virtual SupplyPoint SupplyPoint { get; set; }
}

public partial class SupplyPoint
{
    [Key]
    public int SupplyPointId { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<SupplyPointMeter> SupplyPointMeters { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Can you explain the problem a bit more? Why cant you access `mySupplyPoint.SupplyPointMeters`?

Comment: When I access SupplyPoint.SupplyPointMeters there is a list but no field names from the table SupplyPointMeters

Comment: That's because `SupplyPoint.SupplyPointMeters` is a Collection, not a single entity. try this: `mySupplyPoint.SupplyPointMeters.FirstOrDefault().SupplyPointMeterId`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you to use [fluent mapping](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591617.aspx):

```
modelBuilder.Entity<SupplyPoint>()
    .HasMany(sp => sp.SupplyPointMeters)
    .WithRequired(spm => spm.SupplyPoint)
    .HasForeignKey(spm => spm.SupplyPointId);
```

Also you don't need to mark keys - if key property matches `type_name + id` pattern, then it will be considered key by convention:

```
public partial class SupplyPointMeter
{        
    public int SupplyPointMeterId { get; set; }
    public int SupplyPointId { get; set; }
    public virtual SupplyPoint SupplyPoint { get; set; }
}

public partial class SupplyPoint
{
    public int SupplyPointId { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<SupplyPointMeter> SupplyPointMeters { get; set; }
}
```

This generates following tables

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try it this way.

```
public class SupplyPointMeter
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual SupplyPoint SupplyPoint { get; set; }
}

public class SupplyPoint
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<SupplyPointMeter> SupplyPointMeters { get; set; }
}
```